# Why do we need to create application in azure active directory before creating azure key vault?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault

Before creating a key vault it needs me to create an application Active Directory. Why do we need it? It's not even my actual application (i.e. I have not uploaded my app to Azure but using secrets from the key vault only in my visual studio web application). I still don't understand that part.

Comment: What requires you to create an app registration in AAD? To access Key Vault, an app is needed to get access tokens, yes. But Visual Studio is capable of that without an extra app. It can access KV as you. However, when running outside Visual Studio (or other such environment that offers this capability) you do need to register an app there. That's the application's identity that is then given access to Key Vault.

Comment: If I host an app on Azure, can it be given access to vault?

Comment: It'll need an identity in Azure AD. You can use a Managed Identity for this (which I recommend), or you can register an app in AAD and use its credentials to authenticate and access Key Vault. Either way, you'd give access to the app by adding an access policy to the Key Vault.

Comment: Where were you creating the key vault? I think we could create it without an AAD App, for example in the portal.

Comment: OK coming to the first part "Accessing vault from VS without registering app", I tried that but visual studio's AzureKeyVault.json file needs ClientID and ClientSecret which you can only get after registering an app in the AD. So does it mean that we can not access vault from vs without registering app?

Comment: @JoyWang: In the portal but want to access vault secrets from the app created in the VS 2017. Also, check my 2nd last comment.

Comment: If you want to access the keyvault, you need a service principal which has been added in the access policy in the keyvault, registering app will create the service principal.

Comment: @JoyWang: even if that app got nothing to do with the one i am creating in VS? Or am I confusing the purpose of apps since both are called apps?

Comment: The AAD App is different from the application in VS, the AAD App represents your permission to access the keyvault.

Comment: @JoyWang Spot on, put it in answers box and will mark it as an answer

Comment: Have added them as an answer.

Comment: OK now I undestand. It won't be wrong to say that Key Vault can be accessed via AAD app? Kinda middle ware?

Comment: Actually is the service principal access the key vault, creating the AAD app will create the SP automatically, you could refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals) about them in AAD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to access the keyvault, you need a service principal which has been added in the access policy in the keyvault, registering app will create the service principal. The AAD App is different from the application in VS, the AAD App represents your permission to access the keyvault.